# How to list users with role cluster-admin in OpenShift?

Tags: openshift-origin

I can add users to the cluster-role "cluster-admin" with:

```
oc adm policy add-cluster-role-to-user cluster-admin <user>
```

But how can I list all users with the role cluster-admin?

Environment: OpenShift 3.x

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Found it myself:

It's in the `RoleBinding[cluster-admins]:` section of:

```
oc describe clusterPolicyBindings :default
```

With `jq` you can get the list of users in one command:

```
oc get --all-namespaces --output json clusterPolicyBindings | jq '.items[].roleBindings[] | select(.name=="cluster-admins") | .roleBinding.userNames'
```

For OpenShift 3.7 and newer:

```
oc get clusterrolebindings -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.name=="cluster-admins") | .userNames'
```

Comment: if anyone is looking for how to check a user has a local role binding in a script to know whether to grant it i used this answer to come up with this that works on openshift 3.11 https://github.com/ocd-scm/ocd-environment-webhook/blob/c87f67182b4e49388b9682e0a2c1767b3ef42625/install.sh#L76

Answer (score 2):

in openshift 3.9 the cluster admins are located in different dictionaries(cluster-admin-0,cluster-admin-1, and so on). To list them:

```
oc get clusterrolebinding -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.name |  startswith("cluster-admin")) | .userNames'
```

Answer (score 0):

From my side command for Openshift 3.7+ is for cluster-admins :

```
oc get --all-namespaces --output json clusterPolicyBindings | jq '.items[].roleBindings[] | select(.name=="cluster-admin") | .roleBinding.userNames'
```

For cluster-reader role :

```
oc get clusterrolebindings -o json | jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.name=="cluster-readers") | .userNames'
```

Answer (score 0):

Openshift 4.8

```sh
oc get clusterrolebindings -o json |
  jq '.items[] | select(.metadata.name=="cluster-admins") | .subjects[].name'
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the above responses do not address OP's question:

> But how can I list all users with the role cluster-admin?

Instead they are getting the users behind a very specific clusterrolebinding named `cluster-admins`, not all users belonging to any clusterrolebinding that gets the `ClusterRole/cluster-admin`.

For that, in **OpenShift 4.8**, you would filter by the role asigned to the clusterrolebinding first, and then get the users

```
oc get clusterrolebindings -o json |jq '.items[] |select(.roleRef.name=="cluster-admin") |.subjects[] |select(.kind=="User") |.name'
```